# Read versionName of build.gradle from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, versioning

I'm using Jenkins for my Android app builds. 
On every build, I get some info, like build number, etc...

I'm searching a way to read the `versionName` value of in the `build.gradle` when Jenkins build the job. I know we can get the buildNumber with the `$BUILD_NUMBER`env variable, but how to get the `versionName`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by adding an Execute Shell step which determines the `versionName`, and exporting it as an environment variable using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject).

Assuming your `build.gradle` contains:

```
versionName = myname
```

You can add this script:

```
v=$(cat build.gradle  | grep versionName | awk '{print $3}')
echo MY_VERSION_NAME=${v} > env.properties
```

Comment: Yeah, really great!. What's the trick if I just wanna get the version which is between "". For example versionName = "1.0.0", just wanna 1.0.0

Comment: @ejay you can simply delete the `"` characters using **tr**: `v=$(cat build.gradle  | grep versionName | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \" )`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be '{print $2}' since we're trying to print the version name which is the second part of the string. Kinda like `versionName "3.0.0"`

Comment: In my `build.gradle` there is  `=` between variable and value.

Answer (score 7):

A better way to do this is add a "printVersion" task in build.gradle. 
app/build.gradle

```
task printVersion{
  doLast {
    print android.defaultConfig.versionName + '-' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
  }
}
```

Test it with:  ./gradlew -q printVersion

```
1.8-13
```

Then in jenkins pipeline, add a stage after git:

```
   stage('printVersion') {
        def versionInfo = sh (
            script: './gradlew -q printVersion',
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
        echo "VersionInfo: ${versionInfo}"
//set the current build to versionInfo plus build number.
        currentBuild.displayName = "${versionInfo}-${currentBuild.number}" ; 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:
`gradle properties | grep "version" | awk '{print $2}'`

On jenkins:

```
def versionInfo = sh (
  script: "gradle properties | grep 'version' | awk '{print $2}'",
  returnStdout: true
).trim()
println versionInfo
```