# Increase version Jenkins and gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a project built as gradle component , in Jenkins, and published to artifactory server.

I have a version text file that contains my version , and each time I want to increase the version I need to change the file , commit the change and run in jenkins the gradle task that publishing the artifacts.

I'm looking for a better way doing it- avoiding commit the version manually, might be depends on the jenkins build number .

my question is: what should be written in my text version file so it will take the build number from Jenkins ($BUILD_NUMBER)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read versionName of build.gradle from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442615/read-versionname-of-build-gradle-from-jenkins)

Comment: I need the opposite - change the build.gradle to be the  $BUILD_NUMBER